# Hide Route values when using RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, hide, redirecttoaction

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeOfficeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SearchResults", "HomeOffice", viewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult SearchResults(HomeOfficeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel.FirstName != null && viewModel.LastName == null && viewModel.FullSsn == null)
        {
            List<Domain.Model.PolicyHolder> ph = _policyHolderRepository.Where(x => x.FirstName == viewModel.FirstName).ToList();
            if (ph.Count != 0)
            {
                var searchresults = from p in ph
                                    select new SearchResultsViewModel
                                               {
                                                   FullSsn = p.Ssn,
                                                   FullName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
                                                   UserId = p.UserId
                                               };
                TempData["SearchedItem"] = "<<< First Name >>> is '" + viewModel.FirstName + "'";
                return View("SearchResults", new SearchResultsViewModel() {SearchResults = searchresults.ToList()});
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "First Name searched does not exist in our records");
                return View("Index");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return View();
        }
 }
```

values in the viewModel are being shown in the url like this

http://sample.url.com/HomeOffice/SearchResults?FirstName=testing

I should not show them in the url because I will be sending ssn. Is there  a way to hide them or any better way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` will create a GET request to the named action (`SearchResults` in your case) which is probably trying to serialize your view model fields. Instead, you could use TempData

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HomeOfficeViewModel viewModel)
{
    TempData["Field1"] = "Value1";
    TempData["HomeOfficeViewModel1"] = viewModel;
    return RedirectToAction("SearchResults", "HomeOffice", viewModel ?? null);
}

public ActionResult SearchResults(HomeOfficeViewModel viewModel)
{
    string field1 = TempData["Field1"].ToString();
    if(viewModel == null)
        viewModel = TempData["HomeOfficeViewModel1"] as HomeOfficeViewModel;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: I have a webgrid in SearchResults View. Your help holds good for the first time loading of the SearchResults view, but when I click the paging option in the webgrid it will come and hit the SearchResults action method. Then TempData["HomeOfficeViewModel1"] is becoming null after it comes back. There is a to and fro between SearchResults action method and SearchResults  view. The TempData["HomeOfficeViewModel1"] should not be null to load the SearchResults  View again and again. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Madhu I can't guess as to how you're posting your data, but are subsequent posts done to `Index` or `SearchResults`? If they're done to `Index`, you could just conditionally pass null. I'll edit my answer, but it shouldn't make a difference. If you post to `SearchResults` (that's what you said, but the action isn't annotated with `[HttpPost]` then there shouldn't be a problem. Can you please further describe your question?

Comment: In the [HttpGet] Index method I will let the user to enter FirstName and submit to search. In the [HttpPost] Index I am passing the viewmodel to [HttpGet] Searchresults by using RedirectToAction. Everything is fine for now. Since  I am passing the viewmodel as route value in redirecttoaction method there are appearing in the url. If i use Tempdata it is loading the SearchResults view once and the becoming null when the break point hits the [HttpGet] SearchResults again. This is my problem.

Comment: @Madhu How is your SearchResults view generating the subsequent requests to [HttpGet] SearchResults action?

Comment: my search results will loaded in the SearchResults view in a webgrid in count 15 per page. When I click the next page of the grid it will generate a request [HttpGet] SearchResults.

Comment: @Madhu And how do you *"generate a request"*? Your SearchResults action is expecting a HomeOfficeViewModel object--are you sending it?

Comment: public ActionResult Index(HomeOfficeViewModel viewModel)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("SearchResults", "HomeOffice", viewModel);
        }                        I am sending it like this

Comment: @Madhu You just said the request was generated to the SearchResults action, but now you say the request is generated to the Index action--which is still expecting a HomeOfficeViewModel object--are you sending it to this action? If so, *how?* Please update your post as this comment section is getting cluttered.

Comment: If I want to save TempData for multiple requests what should i do.

Comment: How can i hide the Route values using `RegisterRoutes` in Global.asax ?